# Pasar valores de fila de datagridview a controles textbox y combobox (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms, combobox

Tengo un `DataGridView` en el cual al seleccionar una fila (mediante el evento `CellDoubleClick`) me pasa los datos a varios controles (`TextBox` y `ComboBox`) y es acá donde tengo el problema. a los `TextBox` no hay problema, pero en el `ComboBox` necesito que me muestre el valor asociado al id guardado (en el `Grid` se esta cargando un id numérico que pertenece a un nombre especifico, por ejemplo 1- camión) necesito que se muestre el nombre, es decir, que si la columna ID del `Grid` tiene como valor 1, en el combo me cargue el valor camión (actualmente me carga el valor 1)

de esta manera tengo el evento `CellDoubleClick`

```
cmbJuntas.DataSource = clsBeneficiarios.obtenerJuntas();
        cmbJuntas.DisplayMember = "_razon_social";
        cmbJuntas.ValueMember = "_idJunta";
txtID.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvBusquedaBeneficiario.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        cmbJuntas.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvBusquedaBeneficiario.CurrentRow.Cells["1"].Value);
        txtNombre.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvBusquedaBeneficiario.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
```

y con este metodo (en una clase) traigo los valores para llenar el data:

```
 public static Juntas obtenerJunta(int idJunta)
    {

        Juntas junta = new Juntas();

        MySqlConnection cn = clsConexion.conectarse();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM juntas_vecinos WHERE idJunta = '{0}'", idJunta),cn);

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            junta._idJunta = dr.GetInt32(0);
            junta._rol = dr.GetString(1);
            junta._razon_social = dr.GetString(2);
            junta._presidente = dr.GetString(3);
            junta._tel_contacto = dr.GetInt32(4);
            junta._mail_contacto = dr.GetString(5);
            junta._direccion = dr.GetString(6);
        }

        cn.Close();
        return junta;


    }
```

Gracias

Comment: necesitas crerar otra lista o que tengas en una dB el ID asociado con una descripcion, porque de otra forma como sabra que poner cuando selecciones el numero 2,que pondra en el combo, perro, gato etc?

Comment: hola Manny gracias por tu tiempo, no me quedo del todo claro, me podrias apoyar con algun ejemplo?

Comment: cual es tu fuente de datos? toda la informacion esta en una dB? tu llenas manualmente el datagrid?

Comment: el combo lo cargo con una tabla desde mysql  (agregue al post original el metodo que uso para cargar el combo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás estableciendo directamente el texto del combo

```
cmbJuntas.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvBusquedaBeneficiario.CurrentRow.Cells["1"].Value);
```

Tienes que seleccionar el Value

```
cmbJuntas.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(dgvBusquedaBeneficiario.CurrentRow.Cells["1"].Value);
```

Comment: agradecido estimado!